# traverse object keys in TypeScrypt and ge the correct type of keys

Tags: typescript

I have the following `Prices` type

```js
export type Cycle = 'year' | 'month' | 'week';
export type Currency = 'usd' | 'eur';

export type Prices = {
    [key in Cycle]?: {
        [key in Currency]?: {
            amount: number;
            tax_code: string;
        };
    };
};
```

Both `Cycle` and `Currency` keys are optional because these are valid prices:

```js
const p1 = { 
    'year': {
        'usd': { amount: 100, tax_code: 'aaa' },
        'eur': { amount: 90, tax_code: 'bbb' },
    }
}

const p2 = { 
    'year': { 'usd': { amount: 100, tax_code: 'ccc' } },
    'month': { 'usd': { amount: 10, tax_code: 'ddd' } },
    'week': { 'usd': { amount: 3, tax_code: 'eee' } },
}
```

And I want to create a function to convert it to a `FlatPrice` array, like this:

```js
type FlatPrice = {
    cycle: Cycle;
    currency: Currency;
    amount: number;
    tax_code: string;
};
```

This the the way I found to achieve it, without ts complaining:

```js
function toFlatPrices(prices?: Prices): FlatPrice[] {
    let flat: FlatPrice[] = [];
    if (!prices) return flat;

    let cycle: Cycle;
    let currency: Currency;

    for (cycle in prices) {
        const price = prices[cycle];
        for (currency in prices[cycle]) {
            const amount = (price && price[currency]?.amount) || 0;
            const tax_code = (price && price[currency]?.tax_code) || '';
            flat = [...flat, { cycle, currency, amount, tax_code }];
        }
    }
    return flat;
}
```

But I don't like the fact that I have to create this `price` object and check with `?`

I wonder if there's a better, cleaner way to achieve it.

Here's a [working ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?module=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCiDGAbVBeOAckWAEMpC4AfIgWwgDsYALSmwgd2GAGtCBuAFChIsBMlRoArlCjAGmRHAKEpAZwAmbIsBkDBw8NHhIUcAApQAlpmBrlcAN6CAkAG0ewJVYbosuAF0AfgAuJ1d3T29faVl5RWCw5xcU0nopJjCGKVoAI2AoIRSXGFIQAH1MCA1gMLUYawYAcyKXAF8ijsEuwVNUADFsUhhLG3xwuEm4RRxav1mhKemZOQVEMNjVxUWptIgMmCyc-MLBJdKKqpq6hp8W7qFBADMMzBgrRgQIQeHR2zUABRgaz-UIWEF2ACUYR+IwhbgCEymuHgTyGhzgsL+wARDgRO0mViecABAEJgWM1JC4HIYDJfGjho8lijpv45hgFmdkcB4JgVvF1ugBWtmVMntASTNcHAfHAKf9qc4lksqgx6vKIQ4FXY3NLgAECSqJVApSLFLLfDq1Hr2QEldyVSq1Rq9gcHECtQAyL2asZ682IYIAOjdTGpVBoAAYjU7Ji6TGVKtVxp6xnAfX7bAG4msQxdkzUI+x9HHjei8cGq4yYAAaJxs2b1-m5xT1sN1hBJq6oNqGx0qtoDodLWn0uA1oRDwQJ+UARgcjjgA+IZAoSQHS1UmkISTgHbCc6jUfrBZ7YUIpCvlDatc3U0IunXDYPcAAnCeu5cUxfcn+b3eSxDtOs5gAATIuy5biQ5C7g225aHur5Hp+Z4-kQmCYTecC3iu9BMKwe4IXBS7Iah3boYQGjUdhuFblwvAkUQ6iIS+6SZHAADMp4UdcOjcLRd4gYwagQLgwbYBATQAjA3zotigJgHOkKQjOIlicAElSTJcm-BCinKZCQA) with the complete example

Ideally I'd like to use something like this (I think ts should have all the needed info for achieving it)

```js
function toFlatPrices2(prices?: Prices): FlatPrice[] {
    let flat: FlatPrice[] = [];
    if (!prices) return flat;

    for (const cycle in prices) {
        for (const currency in prices[cycle]) {
            const price = prices[cycle][currency]
            const { amount, tax_code } = price
            flat = [...flat, { cycle, currency, amount, tax_code }];
        }
    }
    return flat;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you can get around looping over keys without an assertion [like this](https://tsplay.dev/w8xY9w)

Answer (score 0):

this is the best I could achieve so far

```js
    function toFlatPrices(prices?: Prices): FlatPrice[] {
        let flat: FlatPrice[] = [];
        if (!prices) return flat;

        let cycle: Cycle;
        let currency: Currency;

        for (cycle in prices) {
            for (currency in prices[cycle]) {
                const price = prices?.[cycle]?.[currency] || { amount: 0, tax_code: '' };
                const { amount, tax_code } = price;
                flat = [...flat, { cycle, currency, amount, tax_code }];
            }
        }
        return flat;
    }
```

Anyway I could save the `let cycle: Cycle;` or do something like  `for (cycle: Cycle in prices) {`???